# MongoDB update creates a new record instead of updating the current one

Tags: mongodb

I'm using the following code to update the values on database:

```
update( { jobid: "10" },
        { $set: { os: "os", browser:"ff", version:"1.0.4"},
        { upsert: true, multi: true  })
```

It inserts values to DB without updating the contents of `jobid` 10 and two fields with same jobid 10 is displaying in the table.

How can i use mongodb  for updating the `jobid 10` contents without inserting another `jobid 10`?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an `}`, try:

```
update( 
{ 
  jobid: "10" 
},
{ 
  $set: 
  { 
    os: "os", 
    browser:"ff", 
    version:"1.0.4"
  }
},  
{ 
  upsert: true, multi: true  
})
```